# I (give)/(gave)/(have given) all the salary I (earn)/(earned)/(have earned)

Tags: grammar

I tell to my friend:

*Situation 1:

> Me: Every month, I give all the salary I **( earn) / (earned)/( have
> earned)** each month to my mother. How about you?
>
> My friend: I keep all for myself.

I think , in this situation, the simple present "earn" is the correct one.

*Situation 2:

> Me: Every month, I **(give)/ (gave)/ (have given)** all the salary I
> **( earn) / (earned)/( have earned)** each month to my mother. But I just decided to keep all for my self from this month.
>
> My friend: That is good. You should practice to control your finance your self.

I don't know which tense to choose here.
My choice is:... have given......have earned.

Can I use “earned” in the US for this situation ?

Comment: If your friend was a native Anglophone, he'd say *I keep **it** all for myself.* Or *I keep **everything** for myself*.

Comment: Thank you for your help, how about the tense of the verb “earn”?

Comment: They're all syntactically fine. Idiomatically, Simple Present is probably more common, but that's just a general principle - unlike TEFL teachers, native Anglophones *always* prefer simpler tenses!

Comment: About the verb “give” in the situation 2. I think “ I give” is a wrong tense because the giving money has stopped from now on. Right? I am confused between “gave” and “have given “ , which one is correct to use?

Comment: You don't need to repeat _each/every month_. It's obvious from the context that you mean 'the salary I have earned during that month'.

Comment: @KateBunting, in the situation 2, which form of the verb is correct to use: “give”, “gave”, “has given”, “ have been giving “

Comment: As @FumbleFingers says, all the tenses are possible - but, as you say, if you plan to stop handing the money over, 'give' isn't appropriate.

Comment: Also, it should be "I tell my friend", not "I tell *to* my friend".